# The parameter is incorrect. Server or code issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Can anybody tell me why I'm getting the error message, "the parameter is incorrect" on one of the pages in my project.  Basically, this is happening only in IE, and only one 1 server.  I have a dev, a test and a live server.  The link has a querystring value "city=Québec".  I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the special french e character, but this code works in all browsers on the dev and test sites, and in chrome and firefox on the live server, but if I use IE on the live server, the link sends me to a completely white page that says "the parameter is incorrect".  I have absolutely no idea why.  Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried the html encoded version, `%E9`, of your URL parameter?

Comment: without seeing code within context, can't say..  If you are doing SQL and concatinating strings, are you exposing yourself to SQL injection?

Comment: What happens if you change or remove the suspect character to a non special character and refresh the page?

Comment: if I remove the french e and replace with a regular e it works, but the next page does a search based on that querystring value and returns no results since the data is all in french

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that Firefox is performing UTF-8 encoding on the URL automatically and IE is not.  Just change the link to a UTF-8 encoded version and you should be fine.  Example: city=Qu%C3%A9bec

Comment: the URL worked with 'Qu%C3%A9bec'.  How can I convert the text to UTF-8 in the URL

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't hurt to double-check the HTTP headers your server is sending ....
... but clearly the main problem is in the browser and/or client PC.

Look at these links:

- Browser language settings (old version of IE):

  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185035
- Unable to create temp files:

  http://www.ehow.com/info_12218814_temporary-internet-files-parameter-incorrect.html

Q: What version of IE is experiencing the problem?

Comment: in ie9 it says 'the parameter is incorrect' on a blank white page.  in ie10 it just gives a "the page cannot be displayed" error.  I don't think it's the browser because the dev and test sites work fine with the same code and french characters.  It's only the live server, and only using IE browser when viewing the live site